# Is it possible to organize the site contents page?

Tags: sharepoint-online, site-contents

When navigating to Settings > Site Contents you see a page, alphabetically  displaying the lists, libraries and apps of that site.

Is it possible to group/organize these into logical groups? I cant find anything useful online. :(

Comment: It is organized by display name of the list/library, disorganized implies some random order which isn't the case.

Comment: Thanks - was aware but have edited to signify alphabetical sort order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is way to re-order the site contents as of now.
But wait for the May 4 announced changes roll out to your tenancy, the new site contents page allows you to sort based on Name, type, number of items and Modified.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. create custom property for each list/library:

   **A) add applicationPage with radio buttons like this:**
   [image]

   code behinde:

   get all groups

   ```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
     //fill ddl 
     SPList currentList = Web.Lists.GetList(new Guid(Request.QueryString.Get["list"],true));
     string currentGroup = null;
     if(!currentList.Hidden) //lists in siteContent
     {
        List<string> groups = new List<string>();
        foreach(SPList list in  Web.Lists.OfType<SPList>().Where(a=> !a.Hidden))
        {
           string myGroup =    list.RootFolder.Properties["customGroup"].ToString();
           if(!groups.Contains(myGroup) )
           {
              groups.Add(myGroup)
              if(currentList.ID == list.ID)
                 currentGroup = myGroup;
           }
       }
    }
    ddl.DataSource = groups;
    ddl.DataBind();

    //set checked input new/exist
    ListItem item = ddl.Items.FindByValue(currentGroup )
    if(item == null)
       ddl.Value = currentGroup;
    else inputNewGroup.Checked = true;
   }
   ```

   save group

   ```
   protected void ok_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      string currentGroup = null;
      if(inputNewGroup.Checked)
         currentGroup = txtNewGroup.Text;
      if(inputExistingGroup.Checked)
         currentGroup = ddl.Value;
      SPList currentList = Web.Lists.GetList(new Guid(Request.QueryString.Get["list"],true));       
     currentList.RootFolder.Properties["customGroup"] = currentGroup 
     currentList.Update();
   }
   ```

   **B) call page you created by customAction**

   ```
   <CustomAction Id="CustomAction" Title="Group" Sequence="0" Location="Microsoft.SahrePoint.ListEdit" GroupID="GeneralSettings">
     <UrlAction Url="~sitecollection/_layouts/15/ChangeMyGroupList.aspx?List={ListId}" />
   </CustomAction>
   ```

now the list settings page look like this:
[image]

**2. display lists group by categories:**

change the /_layouts/15/viewlsts.aspx  (or copy and change the link in masterPage)

open the file from c:\program files\common files\microsoft shared\web server extensions\15\template\layouts

add code:

- replace `foreach(... in rgApps)`, to

  ```
  string currentListgroup= null;
  string group = null;
  bool isNewGroup = false;
  foreach(KeyValuuPair<string,object> entry in 
  (from list in rgApps
   order by (list.Value as SPList).Title
   order by (list.Value as SPList).RootFolder.Properties["customGroup"]
   order by (list.Value as SPList).RootFolder.Properties.ContainsKey("customGroup")
   select list))
  ```

  in the foreach block insert code:

  ```
  if(entry.Value is SPList)
  {
     SPList list = (SPList)(entry.Value)
     currentListgroup = list.RootFolder.Properties["customGroup"].ToString();
     isNewGroup = currentListgroup != group ;
     group = currentListgroup ;
  }
  ```
- before the div with `id="apptitle-<%SPHttpUtility.WriteHtmlEncde(id...)%>"` insert new element

  ```
   <% if(isNewGroup )
  { %>
    <div class="group">
       <h2 class="ms-vl-sectionHeaderRow"><%= group%> </h2>
    </div>
  <% } %>
  ```

now site content look like this:

[image]