# Folder of Lists inside site contents

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, list, folder, site-contents

I have a little bit large number of lists in my site contents.

Is there anyway to organize them in folders under the site contents ?

Comment: Which version of SharePoint are you using? SharePoint online or SharePoint on-premises?

Answer (score 0):

There is no SharePoint out of the box way to organize lists/libraries in folders under the site contents.

---

**Additional Information**:

However, to find the list/library easily you can try these ways:

1. Sort lists/libraries based on Name, Type & Number of Items like:

[image]

**Similar thread**: [Is it possible to organize the site contents page?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/179828/is-it-possible-to-organize-the-site-contents-page)